# Apache Tomcat Websockets implementing fallback

Tags: websocket

Whenever there is a **doGet** or a **doPost** overridden the sockets don't work properly.

One can get it to work by **removing both the above functions**.

Problem : I am giving support on IE9. So as a back up mechanism I am going back to polling which makes a POST or GET request. Now as the same WebSocketServlet doesnt have a doGet and doPost, I am not sure what to do. HELP ?

Does Jetty WebSockets have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is sufficient to call super.doGet(req, resp) from your own doGet, as this is the method that takes care of setting up the websocket (check the source code of org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet).

This worked out just fine for my case, I'm using tomcat-7.0.42.

Comment: Yea, thats what I eventually did. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Why not just create two separate Servlets? It doesn't make much sense to mix the code, if you have two separate components, you can still call the WebSocketServlet for normal cases, and if you detect IE9, call the other servlet that supports your polling mechanism.

Regards

Comment: By the way, can you tell me why this happens ? Or is this a shortcoming in the API ?

Comment: I think it's a limitation in the API... As of latest Tomat version, it's not yet 100% stable afaik...